# Creating and accessing JMS message queue from EJB3 and JBoss5

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss5.x

i'm assigned to get a data from a jsp and put that data to a JMS queue in Jboss5 and then access the queue by a client to display that data in a console. i don't have any clue regarding this matter, can you guys please give me some instructions, good tutorials to newbies regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this article when I was getting started with JMS queues/topics and JBoss 5.  It explains how to go about creating the topics and queues themselves:

http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/configuring-jms-in-jboss-5/

From there, you can leverage JMS clients, MessageDriven Beans, or any number of other mechanisms for grabbing messages off the queue.  For that, you should take a look at some of the JMS or JavaEE docs.

Answer (score 2):

Any book on Java Enterprise Edition will tell you about the Java Messaging System (JMS), and how to submit messages to a queue and to fetch them from a queue.

Comment: i found a book to read and understand about it, Jboss AS5 Development by packet publishing